# Why is it not illegal in Python to be able to add attributes after a class is already defined?

Tags: python, oop

For example:

```
class Car:
  pass
jeep = Car()
jeep.color = 'blue'
```

This is perfectly legal and runs fine. I understand that python is pretty dynamic but doesn't this violate some principle of oop?

Comment: Which principle of oop are you referring to?

Comment: It could be argued that this violates the principle of data hiding, but then Python doesn't enforce that at all.

Comment: New attributes belong to the instance, not class

Comment: Well I thought one of the main features of oop was protection. Attributes belonging to an instance and not the class makes sense but then it doesn't. What's the point of having a class if you have instances adding any attribute they want Willy Billy?

Comment: "Well I thought one of the main features of oop was protection"?  Can you please **update** the question to define what you think you mean by "protection".  Can you provide a link or a quote or a reference to where you've seen this as an essential feature of OO programming.

Comment: Huh? Data being encapsulated and protected from the outside world isn't one of the main atrributes of oop?

Comment: "Encapsulation" yes.  Absolutely a first principle.  "Protection" doesn't seem to mean anything.  Again.  Can you define it please?  Can you provide a quote, a link or a reference for "protection"?

Comment: Well [you can access the private member in C#](http://dwightrau.blogspot.com/2005/07/using-reflection-to-access-private.html) if you really try hard. [sample code](http://ideone.com/KBOEM). I think encapsulation is just another way to organize code.

Comment: Well I guess protection was the wrong word to use. I'll get back to studying more about OOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends

To dynamically set up the fields and value when they can only be known at run time.

Python does not prevent you from dynamically creating instance properties, though you can decide *not to do so* if you have no very good reason to do so. Python is quite a powerful language, though care must be excercise to avoid abusing this sort of power to do crazy things with it's flexibility.